# OpenSFM build error in conda virtual environment on windows

Tags: python, windows, cmake, conda, vcpkg

I am trying to install OpenSFM in my virtual environment on windows, but I am unable to build it and I am getting the following error after following all the steps in the official [documentation](https://opensfm.org/docs/building.html):

```
(3d) PS C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM> python setup.py build
Configuring for python 3.9...
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of 
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions. 


-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- Using VCPKG FindLAPACK from package 'lapack-reference'
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- Using VCPKG FindLAPACK from package 'lapack-reference'
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find AMD library (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find AMD header (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find CAMD library (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find CAMD header (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find COLAMD library (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find COLAMD header (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find CCOLAMD library (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find CCOLAMD header (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find CHOLMOD library (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find CHOLMOD header (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find CXSPARSE library (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find SuiteSparseQR library (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Did not find SUITESPARSEQR header (required SuiteSparse component).
-- Found SuiteSparse_config library: C:/Users/Soorya/Desktop/image_processing/Ombrulla/FLY/OpenSfM/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/suitesparseconfig.lib
-- Failed to find SuiteSparse - Failed to find either: SuiteSparse_config header & library (should be present in all SuiteSparse >= v4 installs), or UFconfig header (should be present 
in all SuiteSparse < v4 installs).
-- Found METIS library: C:/Users/Soorya/Desktop/image_processing/Ombrulla/FLY/OpenSfM/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/metis.lib.
-- Failed to find some/all required components of SuiteSparse. (missing: AMD_FOUND CAMD_FOUND COLAMD_FOUND CCOLAMD_FOUND CHOLMOD_FOUND CXSPARSE_FOUND SUITESPARSEQR_FOUND SUITESPARSE_VE
RSION)
-- Using VCPKG FindLAPACK from package 'lapack-reference'
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- Found required Ceres dependency: Eigen version 3.4.0 in C:/Users/Soorya/Desktop/image_processing/Ombrulla/FLY/OpenSfM/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/eigen3
-- Found Ceres version: 2.1.0 installed in: C:/Users/Soorya/Desktop/image_processing/Ombrulla/FLY/OpenSfM/vcpkg/installed with components: [LAPACK, SuiteSparse, SparseLinearAlgebraLibr
ary, Multithreading]
-- No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake 
configuration if available.
-- Found installed version of gflags: C:/Users/Soorya/Desktop/image_processing/Ombrulla/FLY/OpenSfM/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/gflags
-- Detected gflags version: 2.2.2
-- Found OpenCV: C:/Users/Soorya/Desktop/image_processing/Ombrulla/FLY/OpenSfM/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows (found version "4.8.0") 
-- Found OpenCV: C:/Users/Soorya/Desktop/image_processing/Ombrulla/FLY/OpenSfM/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows (found version "4.8.0") found components: core imgproc calib3d imgcodecs 
CMake Deprecation Warning at third_party/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:8 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at third_party/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:8 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Users/Soorya/Desktop/image_processing/Ombrulla/FLY/OpenSfM/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:859 (_find_package):
  Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
  are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:60 (find_package)
  C:/Users/Soorya/Desktop/image_processing/Ombrulla/FLY/OpenSfM/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:859 (_find_package)
  third_party/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
  third_party/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- pybind11 v2.2.4
-- Configuring done (4.6s)
-- Generating done (1.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Soorya/Desktop/image_processing/Ombrulla/FLY/OpenSfM/cmake_build
Compiling extension...
MSBuild version 17.9.5+33de0b227 for .NET Framework

  1>Checking Build System
  foundation.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\foundation\Release\foundation.lib
  bundle_adjuster.cc
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(276,42): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', po
ssible loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(276,31): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', po 
ssible loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(564,15): error C2429: language feature 'structured bindings' requires compiler 
flag '/std:c++17' [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(565,16): error C2530: 'data': references must be initialized [C:\Users\Soorya\D 
esktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(566,31): error C3536: 'data': cannot be used before it is initialized [C:\Users 
\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(566,12): error C2661: 'ceres::Problem::AddParameterBlock': no overloaded functi 
on takes 1 arguments [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(566,12):
  while trying to match the argument list '()'

C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(574,16): error C2737: 'camera': const object must be initialized [C:\Users\Soor
ya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(575,9): error C3536: 'camera': cannot be used before it is initialized [C:\User 
s\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(576,18): error C2737: 'types': const object must be initialized [C:\Users\Soory 
a\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(578,27): error C3536: 'types': cannot be used before it is initialized [C:\User 
s\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(579,20): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type [C:\Users\Soorya 
\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(588,16): error C2661: 'ceres::Problem::AddResidualBlock': no overloaded functio 
n takes 2 arguments [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\ceres\problem.h(245,19):
  could be 'ceres::ResidualBlockId ceres::Problem::AddResidualBlock(ceres::CostFunction *,ceres::LossFunction *,double *,Ts *...)'
        C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(588,16):
        'ceres::ResidualBlockId ceres::Problem::AddResidualBlock(ceres::CostFunction *,ceres::LossFunction *,double *,Ts *...)': expects 4 arguments - 2 provided
  C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(588,16):
  while trying to match the argument list '(ceres::CostFunction *, nullptr)'

C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(596,53): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>: 
:Index' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(596,53): warning C4244:         with [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\ 
Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(596,53): warning C4244:         [ [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Omb 
rulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(596,53): warning C4244:             Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1> [ 
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(596,53): warning C4244:         ] [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Omb 
rulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(607,53): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>: 
:Index' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(607,53): warning C4244:         with [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\ 
Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(607,53): warning C4244:         [ [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Omb 
rulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(607,53): warning C4244:             Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1> [ 
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(607,53): warning C4244:         ] [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Omb 
rulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(618,53): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>: 
:Index' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(618,53): warning C4244:         with [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\ 
Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(618,53): warning C4244:         [ [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Omb 
rulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(618,53): warning C4244:             Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1> [ 
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(618,53): warning C4244:         ] [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Omb 
rulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(629,53): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>: 
:Index' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(629,53): warning C4244:         with [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\ 
Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(629,53): warning C4244:         [ [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Omb 
rulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(629,53): warning C4244:             Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1> [ 
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(629,53): warning C4244:         ] [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Omb 
rulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(686,47): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', poss 
ible loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(686,21): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int' 
, possible loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(808,62): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss o
f data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(842,74): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss o 
f data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(850,76): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss o 
f data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(885,72): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss o 
f data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(893,74): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss o 
f data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(908,18): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'double', possi 
ble loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(907,67): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'double', possi 
ble loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(1013,68): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss  
of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(1021,70): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss  
of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(1034,70): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss  
of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(1169,45): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible 
loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\bundle\src\bundle_adjuster.cc(1173,32): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible  
loss of data [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\bundle\bundle.vcxproj]
  covariance.cc
C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\geometry\covariance.h(6,32): error C2429: language feature 'nested-namespace-definition' requires compiler fl
ag '/std:c++17' [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\geometry\geometry.vcxproj]
  (compiling source file '../../opensfm/src/geometry/src/covariance.cc')

C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\src\geometry\src\covariance.cc(3,32): error C2429: language feature 'nested-namespace-definition' requires compil 
er flag '/std:c++17' [C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\geometry\geometry.vcxproj]
  dense.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\dense\Release\dense.lib
  pydense.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\pydense.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
  akaze.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\third_party\akaze\Release\akaze.lib
  vl.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\third_party\vlfeat\Release\vl.lib
  features.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\features\Release\features.lib
  pyfeatures.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\pyfeatures.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
  geo.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\cmake_build\geo\Release\geo.lib
  pygeo.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\opensfm\pygeo.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\setup.py", line 60, in <module>
    build_c_extension()
  File "C:\Users\Soorya\Desktop\image_processing\Ombrulla\FLY\OpenSfM\setup.py", line 50, in build_c_extension
    subprocess.check_call(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\3d\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I have installed CMake on Windows for all users, with the PATH set as well, and the vcpkg directory is inside the OpenSFM directory as instructed in the documentation.